# Fiware Cosmos. Unable to connect to Comos to hive service

Tags: hadoop, hive, fiware-cosmos

I can not connect with the servive hive remotely.

I'm using this library

```
https://github.com/Automattic/php-thrift-sql
```

And my connection declaration is the following:

```
// Load this lib
require_once __DIR__ . '/ThriftSQL.phar';

// Try out a Hive query
$hive = new \ThriftSQL\Hive( 'cosmos.lab.fi-ware.org', 10000, 'myuser', 'myaccountpass');
$hiveTables = $hive
  ->connect()
  ->queryAndFetchAll( 'SHOW TABLES' );
print_r( $hiveTables );
```

But the call waits indefinitely until it reaches a timeout.

Comment: Not an expert on PHP, but try by specifying the default database somewhere. It is named `default`.